# Write $\cos^2(x)$ as linear combination of $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ and $x \mapsto \cos(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Can we write $\cos^2(x)$ as linear combination of $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ and  $x \mapsto \cos(x)$?

I know
$$
\cos^2(x)
= \frac{\cos(2x) + 1}{2}
= 1 - \sin^2(x)
= \cos(2x) + \sin^2(x)
$$
but none of these helped.
Then, I tried to solve
$$
\cos^2(x) = \alpha \sin(x) + \beta \cos(x)
$$
for the coefficients $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.
But when plugging in $x = 0$ I get $\beta = 1$ and for $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ I get $\alpha = 0$. Plugging those values back in I obtain a false statement, and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20cos%5E2(x)%20%3D%20a*cos(x)%20%2B%20b*sin(x)%20for%20a%20and%20b) can't do better!

This is from a numerical analysis exam and the second function is $x \mapsto \sqrt{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - x \right)$, which can easily be expressed in terms of $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ and $x \mapsto \cos(x)$ by the corresponding addition formula.

Comment: Using the argument with $\alpha,\beta$ you have correctly shown that this is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say we can do that, then

$$\cos^2x-b\cos x = a\sin x$$ Let $t= \cos x$ and square this equation. We get $$ t^4-2bt^3+b^2t^2 = a^2-a^2t^2$$ which should be valid for all $t\in[-1,1]$ and there for for all $t$. So the polynomials must be equal for all $t$, so by comparing the coeficients we get $1=0$. A contradiction.

So you can not express $\cos ^2x$ as linear combination of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.

Answer (score 8):

The function $f(x):=\cos^2 x$ has $f(x+\pi)\equiv f(x)$, but any linear combination $g$ of $\cos$ and $\sin$ has $g(x+\pi)\equiv -g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You just stopped too early.

Assume $\cos^2x=a\sin x+b\cos x$.

- Evaluating at $0$ yields $b=1$.
- Evaluating at $\pi$ yields $b=-1$.

End.